# 18.04 hangs at after splash screen

Tags: crash

I've recently switched to Ubuntu from Windows so I'm not too familiar with how everything works.

I was doing some work on in my Google drive using Chrome. Had 1 video streaming and another playing using VLC player. Then all the windows froze. Sound was still playing, mouse would still move but it wouldn't turn into the pointing hand when I hovered over icons in the bar on the left or when I hovered over the close, maximise and minimise buttons. Keyboard shortcuts like alt+tab didn't work. I closed my laptop which suspended Linux and then reopened it. Even in the unlock screen, it was very slow and unresponsive.

At this point I decided that it would be best to reboot so I pressed the power button and it turned off. When turning the turn my laptop back on, grub opened and I selected to Ubuntu to boot and it leaves me on this screen shown in the below picture. I've rebooted a few times now and it always hangs on this screen.

[image: picture of hang]

Does anyone know what problem I'm having and also how to fix it?

Comment: We need more data. The jpg image doesn't give us enough info. What make/model computer? If you have Windows, does it boot? How long have you run 18.04? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

## Incomplete answer...

Your question doesn't give us much data to work on, so lets check the file system first...

## Step #1

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`